# validation with jquery and bootstrap and click event doesn't occured

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

I'm new at JQuery and I want to use Jquery Bootstrap validation in my web form to validate the controls.

here is html :

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class=" col-lg-6">
 <label for="txtGroupName" class="req"> نام گروه </label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" CssClass="required form-control text-right" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
 <br />
 <asp:Button OnClick="submitbtn_Click" ID="submitbtn" Width="100px" Height="40px"  CssClass="btn btn-success submit-btn"  runat="server" Text="جستجو" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

and :

```
$(function () {
$('#signinform').validate_popover({ onsubmit: false, popoverPosition: 'top' });

$(".submit-btn").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#signinform').validate().form();
    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $.validator.reposition();
});
});
```

all the things are true and validation is working but when I enter a string value in my textbox (id=txtGroupName) and then click my button (id=submitbtn) the butto click event of this control doesn't occur (OnClick="submitbtn_Click").

If I change this control cssclass like this:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="submitbtn_Click" ID="submitbtn" Width="100px" Height="40px"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="جستجو" />
```

the `OnClick="submitbtn_Click"` works. What changes do I need in my funnction to trigger `OnClick="submitbtn_Click"` after validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery click event handler for `.submit-btn` is stopping any further execution for the click event, including submitting the form, as you are manually calling `e.preventDefault` and returning false. Please note that returning false from a jQuery event handler is the same as calling `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`. (See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)).

So you should stop the form from being submitted only when the validation fails. As `validator.form()` validates the form and returns true if it is valid, false otherwise (See [validator docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/)), you could then write the following jQuery click event handler:

```
$(".submit-btn").click(function (ev) {
    return $('#signinform').validate().form();
});
```

That should return false when the validation fails (cancelling the click event) or true otherwise (letting the post to happen, which should reach the server and execute your server side `submitbtn_Click`).

Hope it helps!